# Notifications don't pop up

Tags: applications, notifications, whatsapp-messenger, telegram

Recently some of my apps have stopped notifying me about messages or any other things. So, I don't receive notifications in time, but then I open an app and see all those messages that were actually received several hours ago without me knowing about it.
If that's not about the notification settings (I've checked that one and everything is OK there), what can it be?
The notification issue is in Whatsapp, telegram, and sometimes Facebook.
Android 9
Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Have you ensured that those apps are exempted from battery optimization?

Comment: I'm rather sure they're exempted. Don't think my phone considers them "optimizing"..

Comment: Push notifications are received via GooglePlay Services. Make sure this is app is also not disabled for battery saving and allows background network communication.

Answer (score 0):

If they are not being shown it means notifications for the apps are disabled. What you need to do is go to app settings and enable notifications for the individual apps.